# JavaScript find string in string between 2 words

Tags: javascript

I have strings as below.

```
/edit/120/test or /edit/120/test1, ... etc
```

I want to find 120 or from the string like that, How can I find that with javascript.

Comment: There's a few ways, what did you try in order to solve this? Where did you get stuck? Incidentally, while this isn't your first visit to the site, you may want to refresh your memory of the site, and its expectations, by taking the [tour], and reading the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines.

Comment: is the string you are looking for always between `/edit/` and a slash ?

Comment: Given that "*[the] text after second / can be anything like test, test, abcd, it can be any text*" (quoted from a comment to a deleted answer), you should update your question to add these details in order that people may, if they wish to do so, offer you practicable, specific help.

Comment: I am sorry if I posted wrong question, I just asked because I didn't found  anything useful and worked especially to the question I have over Internet   @DavidThomas

Comment: It's not that the question is wrong, it's that you've not provided enough details about your use-case, or about any attempts that you've made. If you *haven't* made any attempts then you need to make an attempt, and if it doesn't work then please *show* that attempt and explain what it's doing wrong, how it's not working, what the problems are.

Comment: @KiJéy, Yes I am looking for string always between /edit/ and slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David said, there are a few ways to do this. Given that the string you are looking for is always between "/edit/" and "/" followed by any text, here is how I would do it :

```
var target = "/edit/120/test"           // for example

var result =    target.substring(6)     // removes the first 6 characters ("/edit/")
                    .split('/')         // produces the following array : [120, test]
                    [0]                 // the first element of the array ("120")
```

Actually, let's be honest, I'm too lazy for that. Here's how I'd really do it :

```
var target = "/edit/120/test"           // for example+
var result = target.split('/')[2];      // takes the 3rd element of the following array : ['', 'edit', '120', 'test']
```

Comment: If you're going to take the lazy way then, given that the desired string always follows 'edit', you should probably try `var arr = target.split('/'), result = arr[ arr.indexOf('edit') + 1 ];` (though I've not tested that approach).